# How do I make Windows Steam work properly using WineBottler on macOS v10.13.6 (17G3025)

Tags: macos, wine, steam

I've just installed the latest WineBottler v2.0 from https://winebottler.kronenberg.org/downloads

I clicked on the supplied Steam install button, and ended up with a new application in my application folder - I called it Steam-winebottler.app because I've already got the standard Mac Steam.app.

Steam-winebottler.app launched fine, did various updates, and eventually gave me what looks like a log-in window without any of the usual text.

What I mean is I can see the Steam logo, the Valve logo, and what looks like boxes for password and username entry, but not text saying "Password" or "User name" or "Click to continue" or anything like that.

Here's a screenshot:

[WineBottler Steam log-in window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU0Aa.png)

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444

mentions a problem: Steam client window(s) do(es)n't render any text.

which says "Ensure Steam client is launched as follows...

wine Steam.exe -no-dwrite"

It looks like that's the problem I've got, but I can't see a way to apply the fix when using the WineBottler approach. I see in the Do Your Own section of Winebottler's documentation that it's possible to create a new "bottle" from an installer, but I can't see how to find out what options need to be selected in the case of Steam - Winetricks libraries, for example.

I'd appreciate any clues.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it; if it garners nothing useful, request to have it migrated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was advised to post the query on Super User since the original forum was apparently inappropriate.

Please point me to information on how to request to have a query migrated.

Comment: You can flag it for a mod [ buttons below the question] & ask to be migrated.